# Client side React componentDidMount not called (without JSX)

Tags: html, reactjs

I am learning React and following their step by step tutorial but without the use of JSX. I am not very far into the tutorial but I hit a snag. The componentDidMount method is not being called, and so my timer does not update.

Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React Test</title>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <!--<script crossorigin src="assets/react.development.16.4.1.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script crossorigin src="assets/react-dom.development.16.4.1.js"></script>-->

</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>
    class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                message: "Hello World!",
                date: new Date(),
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.timerID = setInterval(
                () => this.tick(),
                1000
            );
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            clearInterval(this.timerID);
        }

        render() {
            let fragment = React.createElement(React.Fragment, null, [
                React.createElement("h1", {key: "message"}, this.state.message),
                React.createElement("p", {key: "time"}, this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString())
            ]);

            return fragment;
        }

        tick() {
            this.setState({
                date: new Date()
            });
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(new App().render(), document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is there in one place

1. `ReactDOM.render(new App().render(), document.getElementById("root"));`

Why this will not work ?

> Because render will return chilren of App component not the App itself
>   . Your children will be mounted first and your App is neverbe rendered
>   , hence no componentDidMount for App component

the context is not proper.  Try using arrrow funciton here

```js
class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                message: "Hello World!",
                date: new Date(),
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
          console.log("mounting")
            this.timerID = setInterval(
                () => {
                this.tick()
                },
                1000
            );
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            clearInterval(this.timerID);
        }

        render() {
            let fragment = React.createElement(React.Fragment, null, [
                React.createElement("h1", {key: "message"}, this.state.message),
                React.createElement("p", {key: "time"}, this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString())
            ]);

            return fragment;
        }

        tick = () => {
        debugger
            this.setState({
                date: new Date()
            });
        }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App), document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <!--<script crossorigin src="assets/react.development.16.4.1.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script crossorigin src="assets/react-dom.development.16.4.1.js"></script>-->

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: In my ignorance I failed to attempt React.createElement(App). That was the issue. Makes complete sense that if I call render it will not execute other methods.

Comment: With the correct  `ReactDOM.render` it works with the original `tick()` method.

Comment: Yes you are right, the context will remain that of App.